# jQuery Mouseover Image from Other Div

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover, src

```
<div id="menu_1"><img src="replacement"/></div>
<div id="menu_2"><img src="replacement"/></div>
<div id="menu_3"><img src="replacement"/></div>

<div id="menu_1_hover"><img src="onhover_userreplacement_img"/></div>
<div id="menu_2_hover"><img src="onhover_userreplacement_img"/></div>
<div id="menu_3_hover"><img src="onhover_userreplacement_img"/></div>
```

How would I on hovering over menu_1, menu_2 and menu_3 replace the images with the respective images located in menu_1_hover, menu_2_hover, menu_3_hover ?

Answer (score 1):

Better to use CSS instead of JQuery, but if you must do it in JQuery, I can post the answer, just inform me. :)

Comment: How would I dynamically reference these using CSS? Could you post the jQuery as well?

Comment: Via CSS:
1- http://min.frexy.com/article/css_swap_hover_effect


2- http://www.onderhond.com/blog/work/changing-html-images-on-hover

Via jQuery: go for the code posted by: @Peeter

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu_1").hover(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var src = $(this).children("img").attr("src");
        $("#" + id + "_hover").children("img").attr("src", src);
    });
});
```

A working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gtWCY/

To add a single hover event listener I'd suggest adding a class like "hover" to all of the menu_'s.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu_1").hover(function () {
    $(this).html($("div #"+$(this).attr("id")+"_hover").html());
}
```

That should work for "menu_1" you should set a class for all of the elements though so you only have to put the .hover thing once. Not tested. :)